# Check if a condition is true for any item in a group

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How to check if a conditaion is true for any items in a group created in with Linq to sql?

Lets say we have 3 tables: `Invoice`, `Order` and `OrderItem`.

I want to know the Total of all orders on an invoice and if any order items from orders on an invoice have discounts.

```
from o in db.Orders
group o by new 
{
    InvoiceId = o.InvoiceId,
    LocationId = o.LocationId,
} into g
select new 
{
    InvoiceId = g.Key.InvoiceId,
    LocationId = g.Key.LocationId,
    Total = g.Sum(x => x.Total).
    HasDiscount = <???>
}
```

I tried with a `let discountedItems = o.OrderItems.Where(i.Discount != 0)` but I don't know how to reference the correct OrderItems.

Edit:

Order Properties: `Id`, `InvoiceId`, `LocationId`, `Total`
OrderItem Properties: `Id`, `OrderId`, `Discount` - Lets say discount is an integer value

Answers that suggest `HasDiscount = g.Any(x => x.OrderItem.Select(oi => oi.Discount != 0).FirstOrDefault())` look like that might be it, but I am worried about performance since I have 300k items in Orders table, and over a million in OrderItem. Wont this make a query for each group and materialize their Order items?

I apologize for poor descriptions of Tables, please understand that they are just examples and my real case is more complicated.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `Any`: `HasDiscount = g.Any(x => x.Discount != 0))`

Comment: Next time please post more details about your entities

Comment: I edited the question with more details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Any`:-

```
 HasDiscount = g.Any(x => x.HasDiscount)
```

Assuming you have `HasDiscount` boolean property in your model.

Comment: Order doesn't have HasDiscount - OrderItem has an integer discount field, so `HasDiscount = g.Any(x => x.OrderItem.Select(oi => oi.Discount != 0).FirstOrDefault())` would do the trick. Could you comment on performance of this approach?

Comment: If you huge data, why you are doing all this in-memory? Do all the filtering in database itself and return just the relevant data. You can also run some tests to check for performance difference.